# Vatican documents on Pre-Cana?

Tags: marriage, vatican-ii

My girlfriend and I are both Roman Catholics. I know that attending Pre-Cana (or pre-marriage counseling, as it is sometimes called) is a regular practice among Catholics. However I was wondering **which (if any) Vatican documents mention Pre-Cana as a requirement for engaged couples?**

Any leads would be appreciated!

––––––––––––

Edit:

*Vatican Code of Canon Law, Title VII: Marriage, Chapter I: Pastoral Care and Those Things Which Must Precede The Celebration of Marriage* states that pastors are obliged to offer assistance especially by:

> "personal preparation to enter marriage, which disposes the spouses to the holiness and duties of their new state." (Can. 1063)

But this seems rather vague. Perhaps someone knows of a more precise passage?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: I'm not a Catholic, but this question intrigues me.  Can the priests, who are not supposed to ever marry, be qualified to give good counsel to those planning to marry?  When you say "pastors," do you refer to another form of clergy other than the priests?  If you speak of the priests, I would expect this to be a rather difficult duty for them--touching on themes they might rather not be reminded of, given their vows of celibacy.  I wonder if there _is_ any clear guidance on this question.  I'd be interested in seeing the answers.